# rendering markdown files into html in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

My render function to create the html file from the rmd file is as follows:

```
createReports <- reactive({ 
annual <- (some data...) 
..... 
rmarkdown::render( 
input = RMD_FILE, 
output_format = "html_document", 
output_dir = "outputTest", 
quiet = TRUE 
)
```

However, when I run this line, The Rmd file loads fine but I get this error:

```
Quitting from lines 15-21 (5_Year_Average_Dividend_Growth_Rate.Rmd) 
Error in nrow(annual) : object 'annual' not found
```

However, as you can see, I have defined the variable annual within the same function as the rmarkdown::render. However, when it goes into the function render, it does not recognize that there is a variable called annual. I debugged it and right before it goes into rmarkdown::render, the annual variable does exist. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, in the rmarkdown document code chunk section where the variable `annual` is used, set the chunk to be

````
```{r annual}
your_code_that_uses_annual_variable
```
````